# Wordpress how to insert value to an existing input box?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to insert logged in user's `username` and `email` in an existing input automatically.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't insert the value in the input. I test echo $username and $user_email, it shows correct user info).

Would you please let me know how to solve this?
Existing input code (created by YITH plugin):

```
<from id="yith-ywraq-default-form">
     <input type="text" class="input-text " name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="" value="">
     <input type="email" class="input-text " name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="">
</form>
```

Code I tried:

```
$autofillNameEmail = <<<EOD
<script>
    (function thisFunction() { 
$("input[name=first_name]").val(Print($username););
$("input[name=email]").val(Print($user_email););
     })();
</script>
EOD;

$user = wp_get_current_user();
$username = $user->user_login;
$user_email = $user->user_email;

if( $user->ID ) {
echo $autofillNameEmail;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you insert variables inside html insteaof doing so via javascript.

`<input type="text" class="input-text " name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $user->user_email; ?> ">`

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your comment. The existing code is created by using plugin, so I can't add code directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought is the `javascript` part of your code. Although it's not a good practice to pass `php` variables to a page in a way you did, but the main point in your code is whenever you want to use `jQuery` in `wordpress`, you need to explicitly tell `wordpress` that you need `$` from `jQuery`. So i'd say, run the following snippet instead.

> This is NOT a good practice to pass `php` variables to a page nor the correct way to inject `javascript` to a page. It is NOT recommended to use this in production! Instead consider it as a learning opportunity and go learn about [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

```php
global $current_user;

$user_name = $current_user->user_login;
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;

if ($current_user->ID) { ?>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready($ => {
      let userName = "<?php echo $user_name ?>";
      let userEmail = "<?php echo $user_email ?>";
      $("input[name=first_name]").val(userName);
      $("input[name=email]").val(userEmail);
    });
  </script>
<?php }
```

Tested and works!

Comment: Hi, Ruvee: Long time no see Ruvee : ), and Wow, it works perfectly. You are my god. Whenever I'm struggling with difficult problems, you just solve it for me. I'm learning a lot from you. Thanks again Ruvee and have a nice sunday : )